# Reducing C++ code size

Tags: c++, optimization

I am working on a dynamic language (that compiles into C++) for microcontrollers, being a CS guy I decided to do it properly first then worry about optimization. Below is how my object system is structured,

```
Base (Interface)
|
|---- Number (Interface)
|      |
|      |-- Int
|      |-- Float
|
|---- Char
|
|---- Sequence (Interface)
|      |
|      |-- LinkedList
|
|---- Function (Interface)
      |
      |-- Built-in Functions (Functors)
```

Now that everything is working generated code size started to be a problem, every operation has to be represented by a functor, (+,- while,for etc..) so I am guessing that is causing the bump in code size or I pass everything as base class then cast as needed so I have a lot of casts, currently a simple led on/off loop is costing 15 kbytes even though it doesn't use all object types (6 functors + 4 integers).

I have tried various avr-gcc options that did not reduce code size. So I am wondering how can I figure out which part of the code is consuming so much space?

Comment: It's hard to answer when you're not showing the actual produced code. Could you post the C++ code in your LED on/off loop?

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough information to tell you what the problem is (and I'm not sure giving us the information is feasible).  We could, perhaps, suggest how to find the problem.  (Also, if you have two on/off loops, is the code size 15.1kB or 30 kB?)

Comment: @David If i use two identical loops that corresponds to while(1){ turnOf; turnOff;} the difference is 3 kbytes.

Comment: Make sure to use the optimization operator '//'     ;-)

Comment: So how did it work out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During the link step, you should have avr-gcc generate a map file so you can look at it and see what is taking up so much space.

Be sure to use the `-ffunction-sections` compilation option and the `-Wl,-gc-sections` linker option to remove unused functions from the binary.

What features of C++ are you using?  Some of them (like classes and namespaces) are cheap, while others are very expensive (such as exception handling).  Interfaces and virtual functions will be more expensive than just having classes and subclasses.

I saw a good talk once called "The Inefficiency of C++: Fact or Fiction?" produced by IAR. It went through each advanced feature of C++ and assigned a cost to it.  It was mainly geared towards people developing for the ARM architecture but it could still be valuable to you.  Here are the slides:
https://www.iar.com/globalassets/about-us/events/atc2015/inefficiencies-of-c.pdf

Comment: I use both options during compilation, there are no exceptions or rtti (-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti). I do use namespaces virtual functions and interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Trivial remark, apart from supporting David's suggestions: make sure you are not compiling in debug mode and that you strip off all the symbols from your executable to reduce its size to a minimum.